# Firefox doesn't follow the system locale

Tags: firefox, locale

I set up the default system language to Polish and the regional settings to Poland. All applications but Firefox follow this setting. Firefox stays in English

Is it possible to make Firefox follow the preferred language?

**EDIT**: There's something weird in the locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pl:en
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

and `chrome://global/locale/intl.properties` shows

```
general.useragent.locale=en-US
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [question on support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1018686):

The preferred way would be to download and install the Firefox version with the language you need. But there is also a workaround for using different languages. Check the link for more info.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. And I'm using Firefox from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that the firefox language support files are missing. If you open *System Settings -> Language Support* you will probably be prompted to install missing language support. Just accept that.

The command line way to do the same thing:

```
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
```

Comment: All language packages are installed

Comment: @marmistrz: Exactly what do you mean when you say that "Firefox stays in English"? The locale (which in your case seems to be fine) controls the language of menus and messages, not the web content. Are you possibly talking about the latter?

Comment: Yes, I mean the UI language

Comment: @marmistrz: Hmm.. The meaning of that comment is not clear to me. Are you talking about the start page which is shown when you open Firefox?

Comment: No, I mean the language of the menus.

Comment: @marmistrz: I see. Then I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. The menus ought to be displayed in Polish if all the language support packages are installed.